# Get values of hidden fields and check box checked values inside a parent class

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to loop through a class to get the values of the hidden fields and also the values of any CHECKED checkboxes, I need to loop the class as it my be produced more than once on the page as several partial views may be produced from a shopping cart for product embellishments. I want to then submit the loop via ajax to a MVC controller (ive created the backend stuff allready)

HTML

```
    <div class="EmbPosWrap">
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CartItemId" name="hiddenfield" value="167" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="StoreId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CustomerId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="ItemID" name="hiddenfield" value="11976" type="hidden"/>
    <div class="EmbPosBx">      
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="5" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But the HTML could be like this with two separate items

```
    <div class="EmbPosWrap">
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CartItemId" name="hiddenfield" value="167" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="StoreId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CustomerId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="ItemID" name="hiddenfield" value="11976" type="hidden"/>
    <div class="EmbPosBx">          
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="1" />    
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="2" />    
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="5" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="6" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="EmbPosWrap">
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CartItemId" name="hiddenfield" value="168" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="StoreId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="CustomerId" name="hiddenfield" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" id="ItemID" name="hiddenfield" value="1256" type="hidden"/>
    <div class="EmbPosBx">      
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="1" />    
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="3" />    
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="4" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="5" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="embellishmentcart" value="6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){    
var items=$(".EmbPosWrap")
 $.each(items,function (index,item) {      
   alert($(item).attr("value"));       
   var checkboxValues = [];
  $('input[name=embellishmentcart]:checked').map(function () {
    checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
    alert($(item).attr("checkboxValues"));
  });           
});
```

});

I can get a single form easily like below -

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function () {
  var checkboxValues = [];
  $('input[name=embellishmentcart]:checked').map(function () {
    checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
  });
  var dataRow = {
    'CartItemId': $('#CartItemId').val(),
    'embellishmentcart': checkboxValues,
    'StoreId': $('#StoreId').val(),
    'CustomerId': $('#CustomerId').val(),
    'ItemID': $('#ItemID').val()
  };
  const data = JSON.stringify(dataRow);
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("EmbellishmentOrder", "EmbellishmentCart")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataRow,
    success: function (data) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = data;
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

Controller

```
   public ActionResult EmbellishmentOrder(EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM.EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM vm)
{
  var picId = (int)TempData["RecordId"];

  foreach (var item in vm.embellishmentcart)
  {
    EmbellishmentOrderDetailRecord dataModel = new EmbellishmentOrderDetailRecord();

    dataModel.CustomerID = vm.CustomerId;
    dataModel.StoreID = vm.StoreId;
    dataModel.CartItemID = vm.CartItemId;
    dataModel.ItemID = vm.ItemID;
    dataModel.PictureId = picId;
    dataModel.EmbellishmentPositionProductDetailID = item;
    _orderDetailService.InsertEmbellishmentOrderDetailRecord(dataModel);
  }

  return Json(Url.RouteUrl("ShoppingCart"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ViewModel

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Other.ProductEmbellishment.Models.ViewModels
{
  public partial class EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM : BaseNopModel
  {
    public EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM()
    {
      Items = new List<EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM>();
    }
    public bool ShowSku { get; set; }
    public bool ShowProductImages { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
    public IList<EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM> Items { get; set; }
    public partial class EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
      public EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM()
      {
        Picture = new PictureModel();
      }
      public PictureModel Picture { get; set; }

      public int CustomerId { get; set; }

      public int StoreId { get; set; }

      public int CartItemId { get; set; }

      public int Qty { get; set; }

      public string AttributeInfo { get; set; }

      public string PictureURL { get; set; }

      public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

      public string Title { get; set; }

      public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

      public int[] embellishmentcart { get; set; }

      public int ItemID { get; set; }

      public class EmbellishmentPictureModelVM
      {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EmbellishmentPositionDescription { get; set; }

        public string EmbellishmentPositionCost { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string AlternateText { get; set; }

        public int ItemID { get; set; }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you can have multiple `<div class="EmbPosWrap">`? And what is the signature of the POST method and the model you want to bind to?

Comment: Ive updated the post with more details, ill add the class now and the controller action

Comment: Based on your edit you have invalid html - duplicate `id` attributes - so you should use class names instead. And it does not make much sense that you have the same name for each hidden input

Comment: And why in the world are you using ajax is you want to redirect? (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page)

Comment: The end result will be to stay on the same page when finished, and then go to a cart after all is added and also a picture uploaded for embellishment.

Comment: But you have `window.location.href = data;` in your success callback which means you are redirecting

Comment: At the moment yes, but its all up for change, I have tried submitting via Html.Beginform direct to the controller action, this works great for one item, At the moment im not sure what route to take as cant get all the data i require when more than one element i want the data from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179972/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-simonr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inputs in each `<div class="EmbPosWrap">` relate to your `EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM`, therefore you need to change the post method to accept the collection

```
public ActionResult EmbellishmentOrder (List<EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM.EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM> vm)
```

or to use `EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM` which contains a collection of `EmbellishmentCartDetailItemModelVM` (the `Items` property)

```
public ActionResult EmbellishmentOrder (EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM vm)
```

Next, you have invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes, and you should change your hdden inputs to use class names instead

```
<div class="EmbPosWrap">
    <input class="hidden-field" class="CartItemId" name="CartItemId" value="167" type="hidden"/>
    <input class="hidden-field" class="StoreId" name="StoreId" value="1" type="hidden"/>
    ....
    <div class="EmbPosBx">      
         <input type="checkbox" class="embellishmentcart" name="embellishmentcart" value="1" />
         <input type="checkbox" class="embellishmentcart" name="embellishmentcart" value="2" />
         ....
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then in the script you need to iterate the `<div>` containers, and foreach container, build an object and add it to an array which you then post to the method

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    var collection = [];
    var containers = $('.EmbPosWrap');
    $.each(containers, function(index, item) {
        var CartItemId = $(this).find('.CartItemId');
        var StoreId = $(this).find('.StoreId');
        ....
        var embellishmentcart = [];
        var checkboxes = $(this).find('.embellishmentcart:checked');
        $.each(checkboxes, function(index, item) {
            embellishmentcart.push($(this).val());
        })
        collection.push({ CartItemId: CartItemId, StoreId: StoreId, .... , embellishmentcart: embellishmentcart });
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("EmbellishmentOrder", "EmbellishmentCart")',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json', // add
        data: JSON.stringify(collection), // see note below
        success: function (data) {
            ....
        });
    });
});
```

Note if you use the `EmbellishmentCartDetailModelVM` model in the POST method (the 2nd option above), then the `data` option needs to be

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Items: collection }),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer there Stephen, I'll take a read and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your

```
var items=$(".EmbPosWrap")
```

is returning

```
<div class="EmbPosWrap">
```

as far as I understood you need the children, so you need to do something like this

```
var items=$(".EmbPosWrap").children()
```